# Howto bind bindingnavigator to datagridview

Tags: datagridview

I have a function for fetching data from a database via a dataset

```
  public DataSet getDataSet(string query)
  {
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      OleDbDataAdapter da1 = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, sybaseconn);
      OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand(query, sybaseconn);
      cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      da1.SelectCommand = cmd1;
      da1.Fill(ds, "tbl");
      da1.Dispose();
      da1 = null;
      SybaseconnClose();
      return ds;
  }
```

This works fine. The selected columns are "Nr" and "Remark"
I call this function in the next function.
My datagridview will bound with the dataset.

```
  private void LoadData()
  {
     dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
     Application.DoEvents();
     TTT3Dal awdal = new TTT3Dal();
     DataSet dsAWIA = awdal.getDataSet("select_tbl");
     awdal.dsTTT3 = dsAWIA;
     dataGridView1.DataSource = dsAWIA.Tables["tbl"].DefaultView;
     bindingSource1.DataMember = "tbl";
     //dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "nr"); 
 }
```

This works fine as well.
In the form I call the last function and the bindingNavigator.

```
  public Form1()
  {
     InitializeComponent();
     LoadData();
     bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bindingSource1;
  }
```

Works fine BUT if I uncomment this line
//dataGridView1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bindingSource1, "nr"); 
I get this error

> Cannot bind to the property or column nr on the DataSource.
>   Parameter name: dataMember

I tried to solve this by adding the line

> dataGridView1.DataMember = "tbl";

But then I get the error

> Child list for field tbl cannot be created.

Could someone please help me solve this and help me bind the datagridview to the bindingnavigator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never Mind, I solved it with the next code

```
  private void LoadData()
  {
     dataGridView1.DataSource   = null;
     TTT3Dal awdal              = new TTT3Dal();
     DataSet dsAWIA             = awdal.getDataSet("select_tbl");
     awdal.dsTTT3               = dsAWIA;

     BindingNavigator _bindnav  = new BindingNavigator(true);
     bindingSource1.DataSource = dsAWIA;
     bindingNavigator1.BindingSource = bindingSource1;

     dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
  }
```